# How to use a MobileElement to find it's siblings in Appium Android

Tags: java, appium, appium-android

I’m doing Appium for Android and I already know how to find an element using scrollIntoView().

The table I have is like this:

```
(2)TableLayout
    (0)TableRow
        (0)LinearLayout
        (1)LinearLayout
            (0)TextView:Tom
            (1)TextView:OPEN
            (2)TextView:OPEN
    (1)TableRow
        (0)LinearLayout
        (1)LinearLayout
            (0)TextView:Jack
            (1)TextView:OPEN
            (2)TextView:OPEN
```

As I mentioned above, I can locate (0)TextView with the text “Tom” and the id. However, what I want is to locate (1)TextView and click it. Are there any ways to do it?

I’m looking for something like:

```
MobileElement tom = the (0)TextView I located;
MobileElement target = tom.findElement(__);
target.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this using xpath. Below is an example

```
//*[@text='Tom']/following-sibling::[1 or 2]
```

You might want to parameterize the text above

Comment: It actually works but I have to use driver instead of tom.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I eventually do.

Since scrollIntoView() can scroll down until tom and target are both visible on the screen, I eventually do the following:

```
MobileElement tom = scrollToElement(table, name_id, "Tom"); // scrollIntoView()
MobileElement target = driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@text='Tom']/following-sibling::android.widget.TextView[1]");
```

I use driver instead of tom to find the element.